# Use step-down 1.3-35V converter together with a step-up 5-24V converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, step-down, step-up

I want to build a variable power supply.

**I am using a computer power supply and I want to make the 5 volt 20A output variable.**

I found an online website that has all the components that I need. But I have a problem. The step-down and step-up converter output different voltages. The step-down outputs 1.3-35V and the step-up outputs 5-24V. Can I use them even though they are different?

My power supply outputs 3.3V, 5V and 12V:

3.3V output 14A MAX

5V output 20A MAX

12V output 10A MAX

I want to select the 5 volt output and attach the converters there.These converters can output 2A max

I want it to be variable from 2-24Volts. Or at least from 5-24Volts

Comment: Just realize that those are some issues you'd worry about in a professional design and part of why a professional design might end up costing more than yours.

Comment: power supply designs depend on the actual load.  So it makes a big difference if you are driving a motor vs a LEDstring.. so my questions are critical for anwers

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Hey, i just found this video about making a variable power supply. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeYK2gY4z-A

Comment: good for you, but we must know exactly why you need this or what you want to drive

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I don't want it for a specified thing. I want to power whatever  i want. For example limit the current and charge a battery. Or test some simple circuits. Or whatever it comes to my mind

Comment: General Purpose Lab supplies are much more expensive with bigger low ESR rugged parts and much  better protection.  With these Bangood parts you better buy spares because the protection from over heat , short circuit etc... and failure is poor.  So good luck.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 i will install a fuse so in case of an accident i wont burn everything. So, any answears for my question?

Comment: @ΣτελιοςΛιακοπουλος it's exactly the same as your previous question (which you deleted): The experts tell you "It's not that easy, you need to define your use case more precisely", you insist we don't understand what you need…

Comment: @MarcusMüller www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeYK2gY4z-A  what about this video?My question is if i am able to use these 2 modules to increase-decrease volts and amps when these modules output different voltages. Can i use them from a range 5-24V? They can output these voltages

Comment: yes it will generate those voltages  but a fuse will not protect the device from failure to any load

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Thanks for the help! Sorry for being really annoying im just new and don't a lot of stuff. Also, why the fuse wont protect it? If it exceeds a certain amount of power, the fuse will melt and the power supply will turn off. If you want. Anwear the question not in the comments cuz i think thats what electronics exchange wants

Comment: @ΣτελιοςΛιακοπουλος no, that's what fuses are supposed to do. What Sunnyskyguy means is that a fuse only protects against prolonged overcurrent, which might or might not be the thing that damages your load. *Things depend on your load, building something "universal" takes more than an old PC power supply*.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for the help!

Comment: Cheap DCDC converters do not have design shortcuts and can fail faster than a fuse on certain loadswitch responses.

Comment: I am gonna hook it up to another 5V output which my power supply has.This output gives 2A and the converter is designed for 2A so i don't think that it will burn